# Power BI - You cannot see the content of this report because you do not have permissions to the underlying dataset

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a dataset (SSAS) in workspace A, and a report in workspace A that was also copied in workspace B.

People in my organization can see the report in workspace B after I grant them access at report (from workspace B) and dataset (from workspace A). But people in other organization cannot see the report and get this error message:

> *You cannot see the content of this report because you do not have
> permissions to the underlying dataset. Please contact the dataset
> owner to request access.*

**What should I do to grant access to other people to the report?**

Should I copy the dataset from workspace A to workspace B? This dataset is pointing to SSAS cube (so it's a live connection) and I have remarked the dataset was not copied when the report was copied (as it usually happens).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have situation as your, but you can check permissions on dataset level -> direct access (without adding access to workspace).

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

None of the other solutions worked for me. However, I did add [BUILD] access to the user as well as [READ] only, and then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If RLS is enabled then see below details to provide users access:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/enterprise/service-admin-rls

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Power BI homepage.
2. Hover over report, click the three dots for "More options".
3. Click "Manage" > "Row-Level Security".
4. Find your name, click "Edit".
5. Adjust row-level security rules.
6. Click "Save" or "Apply".

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this issue, you need to:

> Remove the users from the dataset permissions and dashboard, and share it again from the dashboard UI, now the users will have the access

For more reference, you can review the reply [**from PowerBi forum**](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Service/quot-Permission-required-quot-to-access-dashboard-error-but/m-p/417811#M44900)  on this.

If this doesn't resolve the issue, make sure to confirm that the granted permissions for users conform to references shared there. (*as reports require same level of permissions as dashboards*)

Comment: Not the same issue in that link